# Can docker containers be made FULLY visible over the host network?

Tags: docker, networking

In our office, we have a small cluster of 10 computers. Some of the computers also host virtual machines (using VirtualBox). We use bridged networking for the virtual machines so that the virtual machines are fully accessible over the host network. Virtual machines get their ip addresses from the same pool (192.168.0.xxx) as the actual computers.

Is it possible to accomplish the same thing using docker containers? Please note that all our computers and virtual machines are running Ubuntu 17.10 (artful aardvark).

I know that it is possible to do port forwarding between docker containers and host computer. But we want more than that! We want docker containers to receive ip addresses directly from the host network (i.e. 192.168.0.xxx). Can you please tell whether this is possible? If yes, how can this be accomplished? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it can be done by 'macVlan' network driver.

First, you need to create a macvlan network:

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 --gateway=192.168.1.1 -o parent=eth0 mynet
```

This command will create a macVlan network which it's subnet and gateway is the same as host's config

And, you can run docker container with specific network:

```
docker run --net=mynet -it --rm alpine:latest /bin/sh
```

Thit's all. You can fetch container's IP and try to ping it in other hosts.

PS:  The container can't be accessed by mother host.

ref doc: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/